# Is the Mod2 (Modp) Reduction of an Invertible (Over The Integers) also invertible (Over $ \mathbb Z_2, \mathbb Z_p)$?

Tags: matrices, modular-arithmetic, inverse, sudoku

Let $M:=(m_{ij})$ be a square matrix with entries in $\{ 1,2,3,.., n\}$  ,and non-zero determinant $D$ . Let $M_k$ be its reduction Mod($k$) ; $k=2,3,.., n-1$ , i.e., $M_k:=(m_{ij} \mod k) $. Is the determinant of $M_k$ also non-zero? Is there a formula relating $\det M$ with $\det M_k $? I can see that in the mod $2$ reduction, $M_2$ is a permutation matrix, so that it's invertible.

As motivation, *not* needed to solve the problem, though,  I'm thinking of viewing Sudoku puzzles, as in https://www.websudoku.com/ as matrices. There is a result that the determinant of a $\ 9 \times 9$ Sudoku is divisible by $405$. I'm curious about what to happen to the determinant when reducing the matrix mod $k$; $k=2,3,..,8$ ( and mod each of $2,3,.., n-1$  for general $n$).

Thank You.

Comment: "It just seems strange ... won't be invertible over $\Bbb Z$"—why would that be strange? The determinant restriction is very strong, so very few integer matrices will be invertible.

Comment: If the reduction is Mod2, it seems to come down to wether the reduced matrix is a permutation matrix.

Comment: How can a sudoku grid be invertible? The element $[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]$ must belong in the kernel of the sudoku matrix?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon: I don't see how : There are no negative elements in a Sudoku matrix. Unless you mean in a mod n reduction?

Comment: For an invertible matrix over $\mathbb{Z}$, the determinant must be either $1$ or $-1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ and $B$ are matrices with integer entries then $C$ is too and
$$
AB = C
$$
then the same identity holds when you reduce all the elements in all the matrices modulo any integer $m$.

The determinant of the product remains the product of the determinants.